# проблема с telegram desktop на дитсрибутиве manjaro

Tags: linux, telegram, gnome, manjaro

установил telegram desktop с офф репозитория появляются странные рамки у окна и у некоторых объектов в самом приложении видно на скринах

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCcWg.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yRub.png)

Подскажите как решить

пробовал переустановить не помогло

Answer (score 0):

просто скачай с официального сайта .tar.gz там будет два appimage
и все нормально будет

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]